# Locating and reading will of Elwyn Bernard Blair who died in 1934 at Atchison, Kansas?

Tags: probate-records, will, 1930s, kansas

Elwyn Bernard Blair was the youngest son of Edward and Barbara Blair.

At the time Elwyn died on 28 Jun 1934 at Atchison, Kansas, he was married and had an infant son Robert who was [buried on 21 Dec 2007 at Atchison](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/67333720/robert-b-blair).

Elwyn had been married before to Pearl Fletcher and they had a daughter, Ruth. Ruth was approximately 30 years senior to her half brother Robert.

The son Robert did not receive any inheritance from his father, that we can find. My husband has reached out to the Blair family in Kansas regarding acknowledgement of his father Robert, and his family. The Blairs are not willing to talk with him.

How can we see what Elwyn's will designates his son's inheritance should have been?

Comment: Martha, welcome to to Genealogy& Family History on StackExchange. I've edited your question to remove the name on a living person in line with our privacy policy https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. If any of the other individuals named were born less than 100 years ago and you cannot provide evidence that they are deceased, their names will have to be removed as well.

Comment: Everyone mentioned by name, are deceased. These deaths can be verified on Ancestry.com, as well as Newspaper Archives, social security, and death certificates

Comment: @MarthaBlair please include links to precise evidence of decease for each person born less than 100 years ago that you wish to refer to by name.

Comment: Then remove all names. All these reported documents are on my Ancestry.com account. Garrison Estep family tree.

Comment: @PolyGeo [this](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/67333720/robert-b-blair) looks like Elwyn's son Robert, buried 2007, so he can probably be reinstated to the question.

Comment: Thanks @AndyW - his name has been restored and your link to his burial added.

Comment: So can anyone on your team be able to help us find the results of the will? We live about 1500-2000 miles from Atchison, KS. Not able to go to the court house to search for this document.

Answer (score 1):

According to the FamilySearch wiki page for [Atchison County, Kansas](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Atchison_County,_Kansas_Genealogy), the Atchison Magistrate Court has probate records, starting 1855. The FamilySearch catalog has some Atchison probate microfilms, but the dates are earlier than 1934. So, direct contact with the courthouse, by you or someone on your behalf, will be necessary. Not everyone made a will and, given his residence in Easton (see next paragraph), search should not be limited to Atchison County.

Elwyn's [1930 US census entry](https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=1930usfedcen&indiv=try&h=33088860) indicates he was a farmer in Easton, Leavenworth, Kansas, USA, who owned his land. Land records (purchase price, mortgage if any, tax records, sale date) may help determine his personal wealth at his death. However, 1934 was during the Great Depression. Circumstances (illness, foreclosure) could easily mean the family was left with very little estate. The Leavenworth County Register of Deeds has land records ([Leavenworth County, Kansas Genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Leavenworth_County,_Kansas_Genealogy)).

Newspapers may also help. Not just the obituary, but also court notices (regarding probate date or appointment of guardians and executors) and personal notices (such as the executor calling for any creditors to come forward). There are a number of newspaper websites listed on the wiki pages referenced above.